# Limiting results of select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to process a select `query` which may or may not have `limit` clause. This query is going to be processed by `mysql` command. I want to limit results of the query to some value but if query has already a limit clause, minimum of these two limits should be considered. I searched over internet and found `--select-limit` flag in mysql but it does not handle the case where limit is already there in the query. Is there a way to do this without writing logic for filtering the query and searching for limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (<your query here with or without limit>) t
limit $newlimit
```